# FBGraph API not coming in land scape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iPad application in which Login is done using Facebbook graph API.My App supports landscape mode. I have integrated FBGraph API ,  but it is not coming in landscape mode.Please suggest me how to show my facebook login view in landscape mode.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Who is displaying the login box?  A browser?  An application?  How is the login box being requested to being displayed?

Comment: Just to be clear, does it work in portrait, or not at all?

Comment: yes it works in portrait

Comment: everyone thanks for your answer, but I asked the question in 2011, now I already know about the new face book sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use latest SDK from [here](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg), Facebook login will be opened in Safari or Faceebook app or will be fetched directly from iOS 6 Settings. It will not open login window inside our app, and there will be no orientation issue.

Answer (score 1):

use the facebook sdk instead:

[New facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Am using the following method, and its working fine.

Use the following code in the view, in which you are going to use fbgraph.

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

    [self leftOrienation];
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    [self rightOrientation];
    NSLog(@"right");
    }
    else
    {

    }

    //  Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||      interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

    }
    here i have initialized FbGraph as fbGraph.

    -(void)leftOrienation
    {
    CGAffineTransform newTransform;
    newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 270 / 180.0f);
    fbGraph.webView.transform = newTransform;
    [fbGraph.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

    }

    -(void)rightOrientation
    {
    CGAffineTransform newTransform;
    newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 90 / 180.0f);
    fbGraph.webView.transform = newTransform;
    [fbGraph.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

    }
```